# Branch.io deep linking does not work correctly with the AAB (Android App Bundle) build

Tags: android, android-studio, deep-linking, google-play-console, branch.io

I have followed link https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration for deep linking integration in my Android app. When we upload the AAB (Android App Bundle) build to the Google Play Store, and open the app via Branch’s link, the web browser open first, this issue is with the AAB (Android App Bundle) build but works correctly with the APK build, as I downloaded the Signed universal APK directly from Google Play Console -> App Bundle Explorer and installed APK manually on real android device.

Please see screenshot below:

[image]

Kindly help to resolve this issue